# Catching mysql errors from php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to catch all kind of possible errors from a database function. My code won't work for me, so maybe I think there is a error inside or i misunderstood something.

That's what i have

```
$appDB = new mysqli('localhost', '12344', '123456', '123456');
if ($appDB->connect_error) { die("Connection appDB failed: " . $appDB->connect_error); } 

$result = $appDB->query($query[0].' '.$table.' '.$query[1])
    or die (mysql_error().'\nAdditional Infos: $appDB->query('.$query[0].' '.$table.' '.$query[1].'); --> Result:'.$result);
```

That won't work - I get no errors, what I do wrong in this case?

Hope someone can explain what my error about the code is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: Obviously `$appDB` is not connected with `mysql_`

Comment: You can't mix MySQL and MySQLi

Comment: And what does this have to do with "caching"?

Comment: @arkascha I think he meant "catching".

Comment: let me ask in another way, how i can get the errors from "$result = $appDB->query($query[0].' '.$table.' '.$query[1])"?

Comment: @newbieRB What is `$appDB`? Is that a library or is that a `\mysqli` instance? Can you show us more code, mostly how $appDB is created?

Comment: Depends on whether `$appDB` uses `mysqli` or `pdo` ... best bet, edit `$appDB` to throw it's own specific Exceptions and catch them - that way they're agnostic as far as the connector is concerned.

Comment: i've update the code about the $appDB

Comment: Oh - it's just a variable, not a db abstraction object.. just use `$appDB->error` then : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$appDB` is a mysqli instance, you simply need to do:

```
if ( !$result ) {
  echo $appDB->error`;
}
```

Or in your specific case (based on your code sample):

```
$result = $appDB->query($query[0].' '.$table.' '.$query[1])
    or die ($appDB->error."\n".'Additional Infos: $appDB->query('.$query[0].' '.$table.' '.$query[1].'); --> Result:'.$result);
```

See the documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php